# How to parse keywords and strings from a line of text

Tags: textx

Have a file keywords.tx with

```
Commands:
    keywords = 'this' & 'way'
;
StartWords:
    keywords = 'bag'
;
```

Then a file mygram.tx with

```
import keywords

MyModel:
    keyword*=StartWords[' ']
    name+=Word[' ']
;
Word:
    text=STRING
;
```

'''

My data file has one line with "bag hello soda this way".
Would like to see result have attributes of keyword='bag' name='hello soda' and command='this way'.

Not sure how to get grammar to handle: keywords words keywords  making sure that 2nd keywords are not included in the words.  Another way to express is startwords words commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your goal you can do something like this:

```
from textx import metamodel_from_str

mm = metamodel_from_str('''
File:
    lines+=Line;

Line:
    start=StartWord
    words+=Word
    command=Command;

StartWord:
    'bag' | 'something';

Command:
    'this way' | 'that way';

Word:
    !Command ID;
''')

input = '''
bag hello soda this way
bag hello soda that way
something hello this foo this way
'''

model = mm.model_from_str(input)

assert len(model.lines) == 3
l = model.lines[1]
assert l.start == 'bag'
assert l.words == ['hello', 'soda']
assert l.command == 'that way'
```

There are several things to note:

- You don't have to specify `[' ']` as a separator rule in your repetitions as by default whitespaces are skipped,
- To specify alternatives use `|`,
- You can use a syntactic predicate `!` to check if something is ahead and proceed only if it isn't. In the rule `Word` this is used to assure that commands are not consumed by the `Word` repetition in the `Line` rule.
- You can add more start words and commands simply by adding more alternatives to these rules,
- If you want to be more permissive and capture commands even if user specified multiple whitespaces between command words (e.g. `this    way`) you can either use regex matches or e.g. specify match like:

```
Command:
    'this ' 'way' | 'that ' 'way';
```

which will match a single space as a part of `this`  and than arbitrary number of whitespaces before `way` which will be thrown away.

There is a comprehensive documentation with examples on [the textX site](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/) so I suggest to take a look and go through some of the provided examples.

Comment: Thanks  been reading the website.  Missed seeing the ! use